# How can I change colors of grease pencil strokes drawn in 'vertex color' paint mode?

Tags: grease-pencil, vertex-colors

[image]

If I have drawn grease pencil line strokes in 'material' paint mode, I can easily change colors of them by using base color button(marked with a white arrow in above picture).

But after I had drawn some line strokes in 'vertex color' paint mode by a way of trial, I realized that I don't know how to change colors of them.

Help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change from `Draw` mode to `Vertex Paint` mode (top-left of the screen) and you'll be able to change the strokes colour.
**But** you won't be able to just change the colour of all strokes at once, like when using a material then editing it. You'll have to manually re-paint over each stroke with the new colour.